# Do I need to manually call .quit() method when QThread() stops running (Python)?

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, thread-safety, qthread

I'm writing a multi-threaded application that utilizes QThreads. I know that, in order to start a thread, I need to override the `run()` method and call that method using the `thread.start()` somewhere (in my case in my GUI thread).

I was wondering, however, is it required to call the `.wait()` method anywhere and also am I supposed to call the `.quit()` once the thread finishes, or is this done automatically?

I am using PySide.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both answers depend on what your code is doing and what you expect from the thread.

If your logic which uses the thread needs to wait synchronously for the moment QThread finishes, then yes, you need to call `wait()`. However such requirement is a sign of sloppy threading model, except very specific situations like application startup and shutdown. Usage of `QThread::wait()` suggests creeping sequential operation, which means that you are effectively not using threads concurrently.

`quit()` exits QThread-internal event loop, which is not mandatory to use. A long-running thread (as opposed to one-task worker) must have an event loop of some sort - this is a generic statement, not specific to QThread. You either do it yourself (in form of some `while(keepRunning) { }` cycle) or use Qt-provided event loop, which you fire off by calling `exec()` in your `run()` method. The former implementation is finishable by you, because you did provide the `keepRunning` condition. The Qt-provided implementation is hidden from you and here goes the `quit()` call - which internally does nothing more than setting some sort of similar flag inside Qt.